# Passing multiple list in a function as *args gives a None result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to pass lists in a function as args but the results give me a None in the end. Can you explain to me why?

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 4]
list_2 = [3, 4, 2]


def total_list(*args):
    for item in args:
        for i in item:
            print(i)


print(total_list(list_1, list_2))
```

Result:

```
1
2
4
3
4
2
None
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print(total_list(list_1, list_2))
```

You're also printing the return-value of the `total_list` function. Since you don't have any return statement, it evaluates to `None`. That's where the `None` is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no return value of `total_list` function, which means the return value is `None`, when you call the `total_list` function inside `print`, it ends up printing `None`

Call the function outside `print`, and you will see what's happening

```
def total_list(*args):
    for item in args:
        for i in item:
            print(i)

list_1 = [1, 2, 4]
list_2 = [3, 4, 2]
total_list(list_1, list_2)
```

The output will be

```
1
2
4
3
4
2
```